# How to change an image on mouseover of wrapper div

Tags: javascript, css, hover, pointer-events

I am trying to set up a simple script where a linked image changes on hover, on an ESRI Map Journal template. Normally I would do something like this;

```
<script language="javascript">
    function MouseRollover(MyImage) {
    MyImage.src = "image2";
}
    function MouseOut(MyImage) {
    MyImage.src = "image1";
}
</script>

<a href="link">
<img src="image1" onMouseOver="MouseRollover(this)" onMouseOut="MouseOut(this)">
</a>
```

This does not work on Map Journal, however, because the template automatically inserts a wrapper div with a pointer-event: all; property. The reason why it does this, is because images are automatically set to open in lightbox by the Map Journal template. So to counteract that, and allow for the image to be linked to something else, the wrapper div is used. So it becomes;

```
<a href="link">
<div id="image-wrapper" style="pointer-events: all; display: inline-block; cursor: default; max-width: 100%; position: relative;">
<img src="image1" onMouseOver="MouseRollover(this)" onMouseOut="MouseOut(this)"></div>
</a>
```

In so doing, however, it deactivates the above hover script. If I override the div CSS with pointer-event: none, the hover script works but then the link doesn't function.

Any suggestions on resolving this, so that both the link and the hover will work? I thought about having changing the script so that mouseover is acting on the div, but then it changes the image. How can I code this in JS? Or maybe there is a different solution?

Comment: Can you add a second image in there that's display:none? On #image-wrapper:hover, you could have the original go to display:none and the new one display:block?

Comment: Yes I think that would work. Do you have an example of code that could accomplish the trick? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to change the template code or will we have to add the second image dynamically?

Comment: We can add the image without any problems

Comment: Answer below for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with no javascript, just css. Always better when possible. Let me know if this works for you.

```css
 .default-image {
   display: block;
 }
 .hover-image {
   display: none;
 }
 #image-wrapper:hover .default-image {
   display: none;
 }
 #image-wrapper:hover .hover-image {
   display: block;
 }
```

```html
<a href="link">
  <div id="image-wrapper" style="pointer-events: all; display: inline-block; cursor: default; max-width: 100%; position: relative;">
    <img class="default-image" src="http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//006.png" />
    <img class="hover-image" src="http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//001.png" />
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: That did the trick! It turns out that it places each image in a individual image-wrapper div, but I wrapped those in a separate div with the above classes and that worked. Thanks!!

Comment: Anytime. This place saves my butt all the time. :)

Comment: @JacobRaccuia what's hover evolution? If you're gonna criticize, give details, please :)

Comment: @MaxRocket pokemon evolve, could have hovered a bulbasaur into an ivysaur, or a jigglypuff into a wigglypuff, etc